# C++ template argument inference and string literals

Tags: c++, templates, string-literals

I have a "set" data type:

```
template <class V>
struct Set {
  void add(const V& value) {}
};
```

I want to write a top-level function version of `Set::add`.

```
template <class V>
void add(const Set<V>& set, const V& value) {}
```

This doesn't quite work with string literals:

```
Set<const char*> set;
const char* val = "a";

set.add(val); // ok
set.add("a"); // ok

add(set, val); // ok
add(set, "a"); // ERROR
add<const char*>(set, "a"); // ok
```

The error message (g++ 4.2.4):

```
no matching function for call to ‘add(Set<const char*>&, const char [2])’
```

It looks it has something to do with the fact that `"a"` has type `const char[2]` and not `const char*`.  Does anybody know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `V` gets one type for the left parameter, and another type for the right one. I suspect you also want to be able to say `add(setOfLong, 0)` - but with that template you couldn't. I recommend to add a separate template parameter to solve this

```
template <class SetV, class V>
void add(const Set<SetV>& set, const V& value) {}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of this! It's much better than mine.

Comment: Good idea.  I do wish that C++'s template argument inference were smart enough to make this unnecessary, but oh well...

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to solve this problem (forget where I saw it...).

You can use an "Identity" type wrapper to have the compiler *not* take a type into account when performing inference.

```
template <T>
struct Identity {
   typedef T type;
};
```

Then define "add" like this:

```
template <class V>
void add(const Set<V>& set, const typename Identity<V>::Type& value) {}
```

This causes 'V' to be deduced solely based on the first argument type.  Once that's determined, it goes ahead and uses it for the second argument, which works fine.